# Circles in complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

> Find the real value of a for which there is at least one complex number satisfying $|z+4i|=\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}$ and $|z-4\sqrt{3}|\lt a$.

---

### **My solutions:-**

---

- **Graphical solution:-**

$|z+4i|=\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}$ represents a circle with center at $A\equiv(0,-4)$ and radius $r_1=\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}$ and similarly, $|z-4\sqrt{3}|\lt a$ represents all the points inside the circle with center at $B\equiv(4\sqrt{3},0)$ and radius $r_2=a$. So, the distance between the centers of the circle is $\sqrt{(4\sqrt{3})^2+(4^2)}=8$

Now consider the graphs of $\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}$ and $a$. The graph of $\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}$ which is a hyperbola with its centre at $(6,0)$ and vertexes being $(6\pm 2\sqrt2,0)$

[image: plot for the radius of the complex circles]

It is clear from the plot that $a\in (0,6-2\sqrt2]\cup [6+2\sqrt2,\infty)$ for $\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}\ge0$ and $a\gt 0$

Now, lets do some case study.

**Case 1:-** When $a \ge 6+2\sqrt2$

In this case the radius of the circle represented by $|z-4\sqrt3|=a$ is greater than the distance between the centers of the circles, i.e $r_2\gt AB$ as $r_2\gt 8$. So, the circle $|z-4\sqrt3|=a$ either encloses the circle $|z+4i|=\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}$(or the point $-4i$, which is the case when $a=6+2\sqrt2$) fully or encloses a portion of it and in both the cases we find that we obtain a number common to both the regions. So, $a\in(6+2\sqrt2,\infty)$

**Case 2:-** $0\le a\le 6-2\sqrt2$

In this case we see that due to the bounding of $a$, we see that $(r_1+r_2)\lt 8$, so there is no intersection of the wanted regions, so there is no solution in this region.

So the required interval of $a$ is $\boxed{a \in [6+2\sqrt2, \infty)}$

---

- **Algebraic Solution**(or whatever you wanna call it)**:-**

Lets consider all the possible circles that can be drawn for the given circles, they are as given in the figure:-
[image: conditions for the circles][image]

From the above drawn circles we can consider the following cases.

**Case 1:-** From Figure-3 (I have not numbered it so consider it in the left to right manner) we can get the following condition $$AB\lt r_1+r_2 \implies 8 \lt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28} + a \implies a\gt 9$$ This case deals with the limiting condition of both the circles touching.

**Case 2:-** Now to not let the Figure-5 take place we have to consider the case $$AB\gt r_1-r_2 \implies 8 \gt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28} -a \implies a\gt -\frac{9}{7}$$

> **Now, I don't know what to conclude from this, so please do tell me that**

**Case 3:-** Consider Figure-4(don't know why I drew the last figure as it IMO represents the same case as Figure 4), the case we get is 
$$AB\lt r_2-r_1 \implies 8\lt a-\sqrt{a^2-12a+28} \implies a\gt 9$$

---

### My deal with the question:-

$a\gt 9$, $a\gt 9$ everywhere not a single $a\ge 6+2\sqrt2$ to see.(It's a joke)

So as you can see that from the **Algebraic solution** I got $a\gt 9$ and from the **Graphical approach** to the question I get $a\ge 6+2\sqrt2$. And the book I am solving also gives the answer interval as $a\in (9,\infty)$. So what is wrong with the solutions and do point out the errors. As, always more elegant solutions are welcome.

In my opinion the answer should be $a\in [6+2\sqrt2, \infty)$, which is evident from the graph figure below.[image: From graphical apporach][image: from algebraic solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be $a\ge 6+2\sqrt 2$.

($a\gt 9$ is not correct since, for $a=9$, $z=-3i$ satisfies the conditions.)

---

In your Algebraic Solution, it seems that you have some errors.

> **Case 1:-** 
>   $$8 \lt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28} + a \implies a\gt 9$$
>   **Case 2:-** 
>   $$8 \gt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28} -a \implies a\gt -\frac{9}{7}$$
>   **Case 3:-** 
>   $$8\lt a-\sqrt{a^2-12a+28} \implies a\gt 9$$

These should be incorrect. Under $0\lt a\le 6-2\sqrt 2$ or $a\ge 6+2\sqrt 2$, I got the followings :
$$8 \lt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28} + a \iff a\ge 6+2\sqrt 2$$
(To solve $8-a\lt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28}$, separate it into two cases : If $8-a\lt 0$, then the inequality holds(the LHS is negative, the RHS is non-negative). If $8-a\ge 0$, then since the both sides are non-negative, squaring gives $a\gt 9$. There is no $a$ such that $a\le 8$ and $a\gt 9$. Therefore, $a\gt 8$. Considering $0\lt a\le 6-2\sqrt 2$ or $a\ge 6+2\sqrt 2$, the solution is $a\ge 6+2\sqrt 2$.)

$$8 \gt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28} -a \iff 0\lt a\le 6-2\sqrt 2\quad\text{or}\quad a\ge 6+2\sqrt 2$$
$$8\lt a-\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}\iff 6+2\sqrt 2\le a\lt 9$$

---

In the following, I will write a solution in the similar way as your Algebraic Solution.

We consider the two circles 
$$C_1 : x^2+(y+4)^2=a^2-12a+28\qquad\text{and}\qquad C_2 : (x-4\sqrt 3)^2+y^2=a^2$$
where $0\lt a\le 6-2\sqrt 2$ or $a\ge 6+2\sqrt 2$.

The distance between the centers is $8$.

Case 1 : The two cirlces have no intersection points, and no circle is inside the other : $8\gt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28}+a\iff 0\lt a\le 6-2\sqrt 2$. This case has to be eliminated.

Case 2 : The two circles have the only one intersection point, and no circle is inside the other : $8=\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}+a$. There is no such $a$.

Case 3 : The two circles have two intersection points : $|\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}-a|\lt 8\lt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28}+a\iff a\gt 9$. This case is sufficient.

Case 4 : The two circles have the only one intersection point, and one circle is inside the other : $8=|\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}-a|$.

Case 4-1 : The case when $(4\sqrt 3,0)$ is inside $C_1$. There is no such $a$.

Case 4-2 : The case when $(0,-4)$ is inside $C_2$ : $a=9$. This case is sufficient.

Case 5 : The two circles have no intersection points, and one circle is inside the other : $8\lt |\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}-a|$

Case 5-1 : The case when $(4\sqrt 3,0)$ is inside $C_1$ : There is no such $a$.

Case 5-2 : The case when $(0,-4)$ is inside $C_2$ : $8\lt a\lt 9$. This case is sufficient.

Therefore, the answer is $a\ge 6+2\sqrt 2$.

Comment: From the inequality in Case 1, I am still getting $a>1$. I solved the inequality as follows:-$$8\gt\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}+a \implies 8-a\gt\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}\implies 64+a^2-16a\gt a^2-12a+28\implies 36\gt 4a \implies a\lt 9$$

Comment: @user350331: See what I added in the answer. Ah, you mean case 1 in *my* solution, right? I added the details for the case 1 in *your* solution. Anyway, I hope that helps.

Comment: @user350331: For the case 1 in *my* solution, when you have $8-a\gt \sqrt{a^2-12a+28}$, you have to have $8-a\gt 0$ because of $\sqrt{a^2-12a+28}\ge 0$.

Comment: Took me sometime to get it to settle down in my head but your explanations are just fabulous, gonna ask more till I go through your solution. Also, can you tell me some material to improve my so weak inequality solving ability.

Comment: @user350331: OK, I'll tell you something if I find a good one. Just a tip : in each step, see if each side is positive or negative. Also, note that $\sqrt{\text{something}}$ gives that $\sqrt{\text{something}}\ge 0$, and $\text{something}\ge 0$.

Comment: Went through the solution, nothing more to ask, just how much time did it take you to write it, coz writing the question took me around 2hrs with the pictures, and I gotta tell you what you are providing is free education.

Comment: @user350331: About an hour (the calculations were not so easy :)).  I would like to say that your questions are very good. I like to answer to the question that the questioner really has (after he/she tried to solve), like yours.

Comment: @user350331: Sorry, I have not been able to find good material about inequality. If you really need it, then you can ask here, math.s.e. since there should be someone who knows about that better than me.

Comment: I thought that MSE is about questions only and meta is the place where you put up questions about these, well got a thing to know about the site, thanks a lot.

Comment: @user350331: You can find tags (book-recommendation) (reference-request). You may want to see the questions with these tags to know what good questions (well-received) with these tags are.